# Retrieve co-ordinates of points from a saved google map

Tags: iphone, google-maps, coordinates

My client has saved a public Google Map with several points of interest marked on it. I need to somehow lift those co-ordinates and put them in an iPhone Google Map. How would I get the longitude & latitude of each of these points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow the following steps to access the KML for saved places in a My Maps account:

Go to *My Maps* and select the entry. Click the *edit* button on the left.  This will expose a *View in Google Earth* link on the top right of the map. If this is a shared map, then the *View in Google Earth* link might already be available.

Clicking this link will download a file that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<name>Directions to Scone, NSW</name>
<description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <NetworkLink>
    <name>Directions to Scone, NSW</name>
    <Link>
    <href>http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;vps=1&amp;jsv=262a&amp;oe=UTF8&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=109115301202341389527.00048cf92603b4141b1cf&amp;output=kml</href>
    </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Replace all the escaped `&amp;` with `&` in the URL in the href element and request the URL in the browser. This will give you the [KML](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&vps=1&jsv=262a&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=109115301202341389527.00048cf92603b4141b1cf&output=kml) that you are after:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&vps=1&jsv=262a&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=109115301202341389527.00048cf92603b4141b1cf&output=kml
```

Comment: That looks all perfect, however the map has been made by another person and I can't see the Edit button.

Comment: @daidai Ah ok. I was assuming you had access to the My Maps account on your machine, which was foolish in retrospect. I am not sure how this works for a map shared on someone else's account. I'll check it out.

Comment: @daidai Just tried it out and it seems the View in Google Earth link is already there for shared maps. So you can skip the edit step.

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly. One thing: for some reason, maybe because its .co.uk I don't know, but the Google Earth link only stays around for a split second, so I had to quickly right click it to save the kml.

Comment: @daidai Not sure what is going on there.  Glad you got the data out :)